# Jenkins: How a job runs on a specific node with no label specified?

Tags: jenkins

I understand that using labels can tie a project to a node. But, I am confused with our existing Jenkins configurations. The project core runs on slave10. But, the "Restrict where this project can be run" is unchecked, and the Label Expression is not specified. The labels in the slave10 configuration is not specified either. The question is how the job runs on slave10 with no label specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Manage Nodes, click Configure for any of your Nodes and review the Usage settings. Some of your nodes may have been configured with

```
Usage: Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node
```

Whilst other nodes may be configured with

```
Usage: Use this node as much as possible
```

By appropriate configuration of your nodes, it means you will only need to specify Label Expression for the exceptional cases.